# C++ Resolve a host IP address from a URL

Tags: c++, url, ip

How can I resolve a host IP address, given a URL in *Visual* C++?

Comment: Sure. But the answer is different in just about every OS.  Which one do you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the socket functions under Windows, you have to start by calling `WSAStartup`, specifying the version of Winsock you want (for your purposes, 1.1 will work fine). Then you can call `gethostbyname` to get the address of the host. When you're done, you're supposed to call WSACleanup. Putting that all together, you get something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

class use_WSA { 
    WSADATA d; 
    WORD ver;
public:
    use_WSA() : ver(MAKEWORD(1,1)) { 
        if ((WSAStartup(ver, &d)!=0) || (ver != d.wVersion))
            throw(std::runtime_error("Error starting Winsock"));
    }
    ~use_WSA() { WSACleanup(); }    
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: resolve <hostname>";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try { 
        use_WSA x;

        hostent *h = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
        unsigned char *addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(h->h_addr_list[0]);
        std::copy(addr, addr+4, std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, "."));
    }
    catch (std::exception const &exc) {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if there is a specific C++ class to do host name lookups, but you can always resort to plain C for such things. Here's my version which compiles and runs on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#  include "winsock.h"
#else
#  include <netdb.h>
#  include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif

static void initialise(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA data;
    if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1, 1), &data) != 0)
    {
        fputs ("Could not initialise Winsock.\n", stderr);
        exit (1);
    }
#endif
}

static void uninitialise (void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup ();
#endif
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct hostent *he;

    if (argc == 1)
        return -1;

    initialise();

    he = gethostbyname (argv[1]);
    if (he == NULL)
    {
        switch (h_errno)
        {
            case HOST_NOT_FOUND:
                fputs ("The host was not found.\n", stderr);
                break;
            case NO_ADDRESS:
                fputs ("The name is valid but it has no address.\n", stderr);
                break;
            case NO_RECOVERY:
                fputs ("A non-recoverable name server error occurred.\n", stderr);
                break;
            case TRY_AGAIN:
                fputs ("The name server is temporarily unavailable.", stderr);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts (inet_ntoa (*((struct in_addr *) he->h_addr_list[0])));
    }

    uninitialise ();

    return he != NULL;
}
```

Once compiled, provide the host name as an argument:

```
$ ./a.out stackoverflow.com
69.59.196.211
```

Comment: When compiling on Windows, use `cl resolve.c /link ws2_32.lib` or else you will get some undefined symbol errors when linking.

Comment: Hah! On Windows, if the name was not found, for some reason it `h_errno` contains `NO_ADDRESS` instead of `HOST_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: `gethostbyname` has been superseded by `getaddrinfo`.  Static buffers?  IPV4 only?  Join the 21st century!  :P

Comment: @asveikau: In a single-threaded simple-case example program, there is no need for anything else. Don't use a sledgehammer to drive a nail.

Comment: My experience is that you never know how or in what context your code will be re-used.  Modern and robust C coding demands avoiding these issues.  It's not hard.  (When providing example code that others can learn from it is especially important to teach the right way as well.)

Comment: @asveikau: I disagree, anyone who blindly copies/reuses code rather than learns what it does (by reading applicable documentation) is putting themselves in trouble. Code reuse is only useful if it meets a set of requirements that match your own. The only way to know whether a "snippet" of code meets the requirements for reuse in your own code is to study the code or any accompanying documentation.

Comment: Fine attitude until thousands of lines get effectively "moved" in bulk in scenarios where a thorough review of each line affected is not feasible (think refactors, library code suddenly being linked in new places, etc., all in a large code base.)  My previous parenthetical comment still applies - if through sample code you are teaching someone something new don't teach them to do it like it's still the 90s, they will write code with these limitations without realizing it.

Answer (score 2):

Easy as follow:

On **Linux**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
struct hostent *he=gethostbyname("www.stackoverflow.com");
char *ip=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)he->h_addr_list[0]);
printf(ip);
}
```

On **Windows**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
int main()
{
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
struct hostent *he=gethostbyname("www.stackoverflow.com");
char *ip=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)he->h_addr_list[0]);
printf(ip);
}
```

On **Android**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
int main()
{
struct hostent *he=gethostbyname("www.stackoverflow.com");
char *ip=inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)he->h_addr_list[0]);
printf(ip);
}
```

> **To compile for Android**

Use these flags over arch-arm: *-Wl,-s -lz -rdynamic -fPIE -pie*

After done, run it via **adb**

```
adb push <binfile> /data/local/tmp

adb shell /data/local/tmp/<binfile>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct hostent *he;

if ((he = gethostbyname("localhost") == NULL) {
    // Handle error: Failed
}
```

The IP address will be in `he->h_addr`. Works on both windows, linux and most likely macos.

Comment: I'm not getting anything, just an "expression cannot be evaluated" for both localhost and for example, http://www.stackoverflow.com. Bare with me as I'm not a C++ engineer, only learning. If I remove the if statement, and simply assign gethostname to he, with the URL, nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the URL to get the host name. Then call gethostbyname or the corresponding API on your platform to get the IP address(es). If you are parsing a HTTP header, look for the HostName header to determine the host name.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int RSV2IP4(const char* hostname, char* ip4str, size_t ip4str_len) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize Winsock\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo* result, * rp;
    int status;

    // Set up the hints structure to specify the desired options (IPv4, TCP).
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP socket

    // Use getaddrinfo to resolve the address.
    status = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (status != 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        WSACleanup();
        return 2;
    }

    // Iterate through the results to find the IPv4 address.
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        struct sockaddr_in* ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)rp->ai_addr;
        void* addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);

        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr, ip4str, ip4str_len) != NULL) {
            // Successfully resolved the IPv4 address.
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Failed to resolve an IPv4 address.
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: As there are several other answers to this question already (and some highly upvoted), it would be better if you could explain how your answer is an improvement on those.

Answer (score -2):

`gethostbyname`?