# DNS lookup in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, dns, nslookup, dig

I must write a C/C++ program which works a little bit like dig and nslookup: it must know IP addresses of any site. It should do things like the dig www.example.com MX +short command does. I can't imagine how can this be done. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows, Linux, MacOS ? Antway, its called resolving host name to IP address...

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151854/c-resolve-a-host-ip-address-from-a-url

Comment: @Tutankhamen: He needs to parse MX records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any resolver library you like. Popular libraries include [UDNS](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/udns.html) and [adns](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~ian/adns/). You could also just modify the source code to `dig` (which is part of the [bind](https://www.isc.org/software/bind) distribution).

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate that