# How make connection between URL and C code?

Tags: c, redis

I have question about connection to Redis server via URL. How can I do that in C code?
I tried to find something about that but it seems every one use for connection IP and port.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Was `redis` tag a missclick, or do you want to connect you c app to redis server? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Could you writ which functions ?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2152093/5512095) for getting an IP addres by provided url. And then you can connect by IP.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's hard to give a detailed answer. But your question iplies that you know how to connect by ip, and if you have an url, it's easy to get the ip from dns. You only need to build a wrapper of some kind.

```
return_type myRedisWrapper(const char* url) {
    char ip[16];
    extractIpFromUrl(url, ip);
    return redisLibFunction(ip);
};
```

So you only have to implement `extractIpFromUrl` which should be fairly simple.